# Force a UITableViewCell last cell to the top of the view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scroll

We have a UITableViewCell with a list of rows that work like an accordion list.

When a user clicks on an accordion tableview cell, it will expand the tableview and is meant to push the cell right to the top, regardless of which one it is.

We use:

`[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES]`

This will scroll a cell to the top, and it works for the first few cells, but the closer you get to the bottom the less likely a UITableViewCell will bubble up to the top of the view.

The very last 2 or 3 cells will not go to the top of the tableview.

I believe this is a content inset issue and have tried;

`myTableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;`

I have also tried

`[tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, tappedCell.bounds.size.width,  tappedCell.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];`

But these do not make the bottom few cells bubble to the top.

I am wondering, is it possible to force a given UITableViewCell to the top of the tableview, and make sure the content offset forces padding underneath it to ensure it has the padding to force it to fill the entire tableview area.

Thanks now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView's content height equals to total height of all the cells it contains. UITableView inherits UIScrollView and scrolling is limited by its content size. You can try to set table's content size explicitly via it's contentSize property, e.g:

```
tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, cellsCount * cellHeight + someNumber);).
```

If that doesn't help then you can change table's contentInset, e.g:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInset(0, 0, someNumber, 0);
```

Comment: I also found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737452/uitableview-keep-bottom-most-cell-scrolled-to-the-top